# Back-to-back histogram - how to 'merge' two different bar plots with qplot in R...?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you create a back-to-back histogram from these two bar plots? I want to merge the bars by row in one plot, i.e. `p1` on the right side and `p2` on the left side of the zero axis. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
x1 <- seq(0,100,10)
x2 <- seq(-100,0,10)
rows <- c(1:11)
data <- data.frame(rows,x1,x2)
z <- c(-100,100)
p1 <- qplot(rows, data=data, weight=x1, geom="bar", binwidth=1, color="black",
            xlab="", ylab="", position = "identity", ylim=z)
p2 <- qplot(rows, data=data, weight=x2, geom="bar", binwidth=1, color="black",
            xlab="", ylab="", position = "identity", ylim=z)
p1 + coord_flip() + theme(legend.position="none")
p2 + coord_flip() + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geom='bar'`  is really meant for "binning" your data. If you don't already have the values for each of your rows, `ggplot` can calculate the value for you. But in your case, you already know the length of the bar, so you are much better off using `geom_rect`, which can plot rectangles. `ggplot` is intended to work in long form, so use `melt` in the `reshape` package to convert your data:

```
library(reshape)
# Put the data into long form - preferred for ggplot
melted.data <- melt(data, id.vars='rows')
# Use geom_rect to plot data that was already been "binned".
ggplot(melted.data, aes(xmax=rows+0.5, xmin=rows-0.5, ymax=value)) + 
  geom_rect(ymin=0, color="black") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

You also avoid having to use `z` because `ggplot` will take care of the minimum and maximum y values.

You can make the bar length along the x-axis scale, and then you won't have to use `coord_flip`, but I find it less confusing to always code the bar length as `y`. But this would get you the same thing:

```
ggplot(melted.data, aes(ymax=rows+0.5, ymin=rows-0.5, xmax=value)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin=0, color="black")
```

You can force `geom_bar` to do what you want by fixing the binning statistic to the identity function (fancy way of saying don't bin), and the position to identity as well, so it doesn't try to stack the bars.

```
ggplot(melted.data, aes(x=rows, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(position='identity', stat='identity', color="black") + coord_flip()
```

Which will get you the same thing as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have all your data in one `data.frame` and create a factor type group level (`$group` in the code below).  Then, color by group to force the weights to evaluate separately for each group.  I'm not overly familiar with qplot, but I assume you could, if you really wanted to, add in some code later on to force both groups to have the same color.

```
library(ggplot2)
x1 <- seq(0,100,10)
x2 <- seq(-100,0,10)
rows <- c(1:11)
data <- rbind(data.frame(rows,x=x1,group=1),data.frame(rows,x=x2,group=2))
data$group = as.factor(data$group)
z <- c(-100,100)
p1 <- qplot(rows, data=data, weight=x, geom="bar", binwidth=1, color=group,
            xlab="", ylab="", position = "identity", ylim=z)
p1 + coord_flip() + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know ggplot2 very well and this might not be what you are after, but you could do this using

```
    barplot()
```

in base as follows.

```
    barplot(x1, 1, horiz = T, xlim = range(c(x1, x2)))
    barplot(x2, 1, horiz = T, add = T)
```

Comment: seems like Mark has the answer that you need.